# Serial Communication (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

Okay so I'm trying to do a two-way communication from C# to Arduino (using FTDI232) and viceversa, from Arduino to C#.
Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SerialPort myPort;
        private DateTime dateTime;
        private string inData;
        const string com = "COM8";
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // TURN ON LED
        {
            myPort = new SerialPort();
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myPort.PortName = com;
            try
            {
                myPort.Open();
                myPort.WriteLine("A");
                myPort.Close();
                error_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Errore");
            }
        }
        private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // TURN OFF LED
        {
            myPort = new SerialPort();
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myPort.PortName = com;
            try
            {
                myPort.Open();
                myPort.WriteLine("B");
                myPort.Close();
                error_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc2.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
        void MyPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            inData = myPort.ReadLine();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayData_event));
        }
        private void displayData_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string time = dateTime.Hour + ":" + dateTime.Minute + ":" + dateTime.Second;
            values_tb.Text = time + "\t\t\t\t\t" + inData;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // PRESS PHYSICAL BUTTON TO SEND DATA
        {
            myPort = new SerialPort();
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myPort.PortName = com;
            myPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            myPort.DataBits = 8;
            myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myPort.DataReceived += MyPort_DataReceived;

            try
            {
                myPort.Open();
                values_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc3.Message, "Error");
            }

        }
        


        private void exit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Exit from Application
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                myPort.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc4.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have three problems. One is when I want to close the application, I want the Serial Communication to turn off, because I made it automatically open using Form1_Load, as soon as you start the debug, it also opens Serial Communication, and it remains on, but I don't want to use a button that I have to click first to close the application. I need to close Serial Communication automatically after I close the application.

The second problem is with the Serial Port that denies the communication, what I mean is that I need to switch from Receiving Data to Sending Data. Here's a picture of what it looks like: [Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8fbK.png)

The the third problem is the LED one. Well its similar to the second one, but this time when I click the button OFF, I want it to switch back to Receiving Data. Here's the picture:
[Application Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuPOL.png)

EDIT : This code is only temporary. I needed it to turn off the Serial Communication

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                myPort.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc4.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. 1) don't close and reopen the port everytime you want to write or read something. Do it only if you want to switch the device. Open in the beginning and close it in the end of the application. "that I need to switch from Receiving Data to Sending Data." why is this? where does this restriction come from?

Comment: 2) what you do in this line: `inData = myPort.ReadLine();` is very dangerous. You are using a class variable, which you access in a different method. `MyPort_DataReceived` is fired on a different thread, the `inData` can be overriden by the next incoming message before the first one gets the chance to write it on the UI

Comment: Basically it denies my COM8, when I try to click on the ON button. It says "COM8 is denied" or something like that, and that's because the "Receiving Data" is already connected and it can't connect at the same time with the "Send Data", so it gives me this Denied error.

Comment: The one about inData I know. Because everytime I click the physical button, I want it to update the last message. Or maybe I didn't understand well what you meant.

Comment: The access denied error is because you open the port multiple times (and never dispose it). Open the port once and keep a member so you can access it from multiple places.

Comment: Oh, but how do I do that? If I may ask. Sorry for the ignorance. I'm quite a newbie at programming.

Comment: "how do I do that? " remove the opening and closing parts from the button click methods

Comment: use the `FormsClosing` event to close the port and dispose it. Can you please elaborate more on the modes of operation? how do you mean that you have a sending and receiving mode? Because if you use the `myPort.DataReceived` you read automatically from the port when the device decides to send you data.

Comment: "use the FormsClosing event to close the port and dispose it" @MongZhu yes I used it. Thank you a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing and opening the port many times. This is not allowed. Use a single initialization and keep the member. This makes the code much smoother, too.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SerialPort myPort;
        private DateTime dateTime;
        const string com = "COM8";
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // TURN ON LED
        {
            try
            {
                myPort.WriteLine("A");
                error_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Errore");
            }
        }
        private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // TURN OFF LED
        {
            try
            {
                myPort.WriteLine("B");
                error_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc2.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
        void MyPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var inData = myPort.ReadLine(); // Use local variable
            
            Invoke(new Action<string>(displayData_event), inData);
        }
        private void displayData_event(string data)
        {
            dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string time = dateTime.Hour + ":" + dateTime.Minute + ":" + dateTime.Second;
            values_tb.Text = time + "\t\t\t\t\t" + data;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // PRESS PHYSICAL BUTTON TO SEND DATA
        {
            myPort = new SerialPort();
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myPort.PortName = com;
            myPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            myPort.DataBits = 8;
            myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myPort.DataReceived += MyPort_DataReceived;

            try
            {
                myPort.Open();
                values_tb.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception exc3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc3.Message, "Error");
            }

        }
    
        private void exit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Exit from Application
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                myPort.Close();
                myPort = null;
            }
            catch (Exception exc4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc4.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I also fixed your event handling. One handler that gets the data and then forwards the received text is enough. You would also not really require the exception handling around `WriteLine` now, since that cannot really fail.

Comment: this: `displayData_event(inData);` doesn't work. You need to Invoke the method, otherwise  the manipulation of a UI element like `values_tb.Text = time + "\t\t\t\t\t" + data;` will lead to an exception, since `MyPort_DataReceived` is fired on a different thread

Comment: To me it actually works well now. I can both send and receive data at the same time. Although I have no idea if the Serial Communication closes after the application is closed (unless I use a button yeah, but I wanted to close the com just by closing the application)

Comment: @KilerKazanu "To me it actually works well now. " because you probably have still the invoke line : `this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayData_event));` in your code... am I right?

Comment: @MongZhu "because you probably have still the invoke line". I think yes, that may be the cause

Comment: @PMF please fix your answer, it will be very confusing for future visitors is they use your code and it will throw exceptions

Comment: @MongZhu Updated code now, I just overlooked that cross-thread problem here.

Comment: @KilerKazanu The port is certainly closed if the application terminates. If you want to do it right, though, you should add a handler for the `Closing` event of the form and do the same as in `button2_Click`.